# Using v4l2loopback and GStreamer with MJPEG cameras

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline, mjpeg

I have one 4k camera which has MJPEG and YUY2 formats. Currently, I can run

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video20 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video21
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

And stream `video1` image to two different devices.

Q: How to pass MJPEG image from `video1` to both `video20` and `video21`, which are in `YUY2` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MJPEG case you need to add `image/jpeg` caps to v4l2src. After `v4l2src` you need to convert it to raw video.

Gstreamer has `jpegdec` and `avdec_mjpeg` plugins. In my current version `jpegdec` does not support `YUY2` output, so I would use `avdec_mjpeg`. Alernatively you can use `jpegdec` with `videoconvert` (i.e.`... ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! ...`).

The following line should do it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! "image/jpeg,width=3840,height=2160,framerate=30/1" ! avdec_mjpeg ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=3840,height=2160,framerate=30/1" ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video20 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video21
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but I am testing those commands on standard kernels and also on custom ones. I am having some problems with the customized kernel because the pipeline is working, but I can't see the device when I try to access it on webrtc